# Expected number of draws to find a match

Tags: probability, expectation

Suppose I have $n$ pairs of socks in a drawer, well mixed, with each pair distinct, so each sock has one unique match. I begin drawing socks one-at-a-time, at random, without replacement. Let $X_n$ be a random variable representing the number of draws necessary to find one matching pair.

Is there a nice way to describe the distribution function of $X_n$? What is its expected value? Does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{E(X_n)}{n}$ exist, and if so, what is it?

It is clear that the support of the distribution is the set of integers $\{2,\ldots,n+1\}$. I have calculated the distribution and expectation for the first few values of $n$; I believe the following is without error:

$n=1$:

> $\begin{matrix}x & P(X_1=x)\\ 2 & 1\end{matrix}$
>
> $E(X_1)=2$

$n=2$:

> $\begin{matrix}x & P(X_2=x)\\ 2 & \frac13\\ 3 & \frac23 \end{matrix}$
>
> $E(X_2)=\frac83$

$n=3$:

> $\begin{matrix}x & P(X_3=x)\\ 2 & \frac15\\ 3 & \frac25\\ 4 & \frac25 \end{matrix}$
>
> $E(X_3)=\frac{16}5$

$n=4$:

> $\begin{matrix}x & P(X_4=x)\\ 2 & \frac17\\ 3 & \frac27\\ 4 & \frac{12}{35}\\ 5 & \frac{8}{35} \end{matrix}$
>
> $E(X_4)=\frac{128}{35}$

$n=5$:

> $\begin{matrix}x & P(X_5=x)\\ 2 & \frac19\\ 3 & \frac29\\ 4 & \frac27\\ 5 & \frac{16}{63}\\ 6 & \frac{8}{63} \end{matrix}$
>
> $E(X_5)=\frac{256}{63}$

From this work so far, I find it striking that the numerators are all powers of $2$. The first two probabilities in each table ($n>1$) are $\frac{1}{2n-1}$ and $\frac{2}{2n-1}$, and this is easy to show. After that.... the patterns seem a little more elusive.

I conjecture that the limit of $\frac{E(X_n)}{n}$ exists and is greater than $0$, but I don't know what it is. Its first few values, rounded, are $2, 1.333, 1.067, 0.914, 0.813$

Any ideas, insights, or references are very much appreciated. This is not a problem from a class or anything; it just comes from my own curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you pick socks without replacement $k$ times, $2\leq k\leq n+1$, when you find the first match. When you pick socks the first time there are $N\equiv 2n$ ways of doing it.

If there is to be no match during second pick, then there are $N(N-2)$ ways of picking the second sock, because for each sock picked the first time there are $(N-2)$ socks that we could pick the second time without having a match.

If there is to be no match during third pick, then there are $N(N-2)(N-4)$ ways of picking the third sock. This is because after two picks without a match, there are $(N-2)$ socks left, and for there are to be no match in the third pick there are $(N-2)-2$ choices available.

If there is to be no match during fourth pick, then there are $N(N-2)(N-4)(N-6)$ ways of picking the second sock. This is because after three picks without a match, there are $(N-3)$ socks left, and for there are to be no match in the fourth pick there are $(N-3)-3$ choices available.

Since the first match occurs on $k$-th picking, there has been no match during the previous $(k-1)$ pickings. The number of ways for there to be no match during $(k-1)$ pickings is:
\begin{align}
 &N(N-2)(N-4)...(N-2(k-2))\\
=&2^{k-1}n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-(k-2))\\
=&2^{k-1}\prod_{i=0}^{k-2}(n-i)
\end{align}
 Since you have picked $(k-1)$ distinct socks so far, to get a match on $k$-th picking we must pick one of the $(k-1)$ socks. Therefore the total number of ways to get the first match on $k$-th pick is: $N(N-2)(N-4)...(N-2(k-1))(k-1)$.
\begin{align}
(k-1)2^{k-1}\prod_{i=0}^{k-2}(n-i)
\end{align}

Since there are a total of $N(N-1)(N-2)...(N-(k-1))=\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(2n-i)$ ways to select socks without replacement in $k$ picks the sought for probability is:
\begin{align}
\frac{(k-1)2^{k-1}\prod_{i=0}^{k-2}(n-i)}{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(2n-i)}
\end{align}
This formula correctly reproduces your results. Using Mathematica I get the $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{E[X_n]}{n}=0$.

Comment: It doesn’t look like we can expect a nice closed form for $E(X_n)$, does it? Nice answer!

Comment: @GTonyJacobs According to Mathematica: $E(X_n)=\sqrt{\pi}n!/((2n-1)/2)!$.

Comment: Which simplifies to $4^n (n!)^2/(2n)!$ or $$\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}$$ so the powers of 2 on top weren’t a coincidence!

Comment: Using Stirling’s approximation, we get $E[X_n]\sim \sqrt{\pi n}$, which makes it clear why that limit is $0$.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Well done.

Comment: The square-root dependence reminds me of the birthday problem, although the exact calculations aren't the same because there's dependency between trials while the birthday problem has independent trials.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I would be much obliged if you briefly showed me how you arrived at the first simplification $4^n/(2n,n)$.

Comment: I evaluated the bottom factorial using the formula for the gamma function of a half-integer that I found on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5):

**Introductory remark.**  This answer was originally  written to treat
the  case of  seeing the  first  repeated value  when drawing  without
replacement  from   a  deck  of   cards  as  proposed  at   this  [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2450596/).   It answers
the corresponding case of $n$ pairs of socks as well, however, consult
the end of the document for this.

We solve the problem where we have  $j$ instances of each of $n$ types
of coupons and draw without replacement until we have seen $2$ coupons
of some type.  For a deck of  cards we have $13$ types  of coupons and
$4$ instances  of each  type.  Using the  notation from  the following
[MSE  link  I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172876/)  and
[MSE  link  II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401573/)  we
introduce the marked generating function

$$\left(1 + j w z\right)^n.$$

The coefficient on $[z^m]$  here represents distributions of sequences
of $m$  draws from the $n$  types according to probability,  where the
ones that occur one  time have been marked. Each of  the latter may be
augmented to  a pair of some  color where the weight  is $j-1$ because
one  coupon has  already been  drawn.  As  we only  need the  count we
differentiate with respect to $w$ and set $w=1$, getting

$$n\times \left(1 + jz\right)^{n-1}
\times j z.$$

With  the  method  from  the  linked posts  we  thus  obtain  for  the
probability

$$P[T = m] = \frac{1}{m!} {nj\choose m}^{-1}
(m-1)! \times (j-1) \times [z^{m-1}] n j z (1 + jz)^{n-1}
\\ = \frac{nj}{m} {nj\choose m}^{-1}  \times (j-1) \times
[z^{m-2}] (1 + jz)^{n-1}
\\ = \frac{nj}{m} {nj\choose m}^{-1}  \times (j-1) \times
{n-1\choose m-2} j^{m-2}
\\ = (j-1) \times {nj-1\choose m-1}^{-1} 
{n-1\choose m-2} j^{m-2}.$$

Next  we  **verify that  this  is  a probability  distribution.**  The
process may  halt after  two steps  at the earliest  and $n+1$  at the
latest and we get

$$\sum_{m=2}^{n+1} P[T=m] =
(j-1) \sum_{m=2}^{n+1} {nj-1\choose m-1}^{-1} 
{n-1\choose m-2} j^{m-2}
\\ = (j-1) \sum_{m=2}^{n+1} {nj-1\choose m-1}^{-1} \frac{m-1}{n}
{n\choose m-1} j^{m-2}
\\ = \frac{j-1}{n} \sum_{m=2}^{n+1} {nj-1\choose m-1}^{-1}
{n\choose m-1} (m-1) j^{m-2}.$$

We have

$${nj-1\choose m-1}^{-1}
{n\choose m-1} = \frac{n!\times (nj-m)!}{(nj-1)!\times (n-(m-1))!}
\\ = {nj-1\choose n}^{-1} {nj-m\choose n-(m-1)}.$$

Here we have used the fact that for the scenario to make sense we must
have $j\ge 2.$ Continuing we find

$$\frac{j-1}{n} {nj-1\choose n}^{-1}
\sum_{m=2}^{n+1} {nj-m\choose n-(m-1)} (m-1) j^{m-2}$$

The sum term yields

$$\sum_{m=1}^{n} {nj-1-m\choose n-m} m j^{m-1}
= \sum_{m\ge 1} [w^{n-m}] (1+w)^{nj-1-m} m j^{m-1}
\\ =  [w^n] (1+w)^{nj-1} 
\sum_{m\ge 1} w^m (1+w)^{-m} m j^{m-1}
\\ = [w^n] (1+w)^{nj-1} \frac{w}{(1+w)}
\sum_{m\ge 1} w^{m-1} (1+w)^{-(m-1)} m j^{m-1}
\\ = [w^n] (1+w)^{nj-1} \frac{w}{(1+w)} \frac{1}{(1-wj/(1+w))^2}
\\ = [w^{n-1}] (1+w)^{nj} \frac{1}{(1+w-wj)^2}
= [w^{n-1}] (1+w)^{nj} \frac{1}{(1-(j-1)w)^2}.$$

Extracting coefficients we find

$$\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {nj\choose n-1-q} (q+1) (j-1)^q
= \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {nj\choose nj-n+q+1} (q+1) (j-1)^q
\\ = nj \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {nj-1\choose nj-n+q} (j-1)^q
- n(j-1) \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {nj\choose nj-n+q+1} (j-1)^q
\\ = n  \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {nj-1\choose nj-n+q} (j-1)^{q+1}
+ n \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {nj-1\choose nj-n+q} (j-1)^q
\\ - n \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {nj\choose nj-n+q+1} (j-1)^{q+1}
\\ = n  \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {nj-1\choose nj-n+q} (j-1)^{q+1}
+ n \sum_{q=-1}^{n-2} {nj-1\choose nj-n+q+1} (j-1)^{q+1}
\\ - n \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {nj\choose nj-n+q+1} (j-1)^{q+1}
\\ = n  \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {nj-1\choose nj-n+q} (j-1)^{q+1}
+ n \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {nj-1\choose nj-n+q+1} (j-1)^{q+1}
\\ + n {nj-1\choose nj-n} 
- n \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {nj\choose nj-n+q+1} (j-1)^{q+1}
= n {nj-1\choose nj-n}.$$

Collecting everything we obtain

$$\frac{j-1}{n} {nj-1\choose n}^{-1} 
\times n \times {nj-1\choose n-1} 
\\ = \frac{j-1}{n} {nj-1\choose n}^{-1} 
\times n \times {nj-1\choose n} \frac{n}{nj-n}
= 1$$

and we have confirmed that we have a probability distribution.

The next step is to **compute the expectation.** Recapitulating the earlier
computation we find that

$$E[T] = \sum_{m=2}^{n+1} m P[T=m]
= \frac{j-1}{n} {nj-1\choose n}^{-1}
\sum_{m=1}^{n} {nj-1-m\choose n-m} (m+1) m j^{m-1}$$

or

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
E[T] = \frac{2(j-1)}{n} {nj-1\choose n}^{-1} 
[w^{n-1}] (1+w)^{nj+1} \frac{1}{(1-(j-1)w)^3}.}$$

Extracting coefficients we obtain the closed form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
E[T] = \frac{(j-1)}{n} {nj-1\choose n}^{-1} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {nj+1\choose n-1-q} (q+2)(q+1) (j-1)^q.}$$

Observe that for a deck of cards we get

$$E[T] = {\frac {226087256246}{39688347475}} \approx 5.696565129.$$

Furthermore    this    simplifies     when    $j=2$    (pairs    of
socks). Instantiating $j$ to $2$ will produce

$$\frac{2}{n} {2n-1\choose n}^{-1}
[w^{n-1}] (1+w)^{2n+1} \frac{1}{(1-w)^3}.$$

The coefficient is

$$\mathrm{Res}_{w=0} \frac{1}{w^n} (1+w)^{2n+1} \frac{1}{(1-w)^3}.$$

Note that the residue at infinity is given by

$$- \mathrm{Res}_{w=0} \frac{1}{w^2} w^n \frac{(1+w)^{2n+1}}{w^{2n+1}} 
\frac{1}{(1-1/w)^3}
= - \mathrm{Res}_{w=0} \frac{1}{w^2} \frac{(1+w)^{2n+1}}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{w^3}{(w-1)^3}
\\ = \mathrm{Res}_{w=0} \frac{(1+w)^{2n+1}}{w^{n}} 
\frac{1}{(1-w)^3}.$$

Hence the value is minus half the residue at $w=1$. We find
with $(1-w)^3 = - (w-1)^3$

$$\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} \left.\frac{1}{w^n} (1+w)^{2n+1}
\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{w^2} - \frac{2n(2n+1)}{w (1+w)}
+ \frac{(2n+1)(2n)}{(1+w)^2}\right)\right|_{w=1}
\\ = 2^{2n-1} \left(n^2+n - 2n^2-n + n^2 + \frac{1}{2} n\right)
= \frac{1}{4} n 4^n.$$

Now observe that

$${2n-1\choose  n}^{-1}   =  {2n\choose   n}^{-1}  \times   2n  \times
\frac{1}{n} = 2 {2n\choose n}^{-1}
\sim 2 \times \frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{4^n}$$

We thus have the closed form for $j=2$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
E[T] = {2n-1\choose n}^{-1} \frac{1}{2} 4^n
= {2n\choose n}^{-1} 4^n.}$$

and we get the nice asymptotic

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
E[T] \sim \sqrt{\pi n}.}$$

There is also  a very basic C program which  confirmed the closed form
of the  expectations for  all combinations  of $n$  and $j$  that were
examined. For example with $j=5$ we get the expectations

$$2,{\frac {23}{9}},{\frac {272}{91}},{\frac {3253}{969}},
{\frac {6522}{1771}},{\frac {94477}{23751}},
{\frac {714436}{168113}},{\frac {69263329}{15380937}},\ldots$$

with values

$$2, 2.555555556, 2.989010989, 3.357069143, 3.682665161,
\\ 3.977811461, 4.249736784, 4.503193076,\ldots $$

Running the program  on $10^8$ trials will then match  these values to
about five digits decimal precision.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int n = 6 , j = 3, trials = 1000; 

  if(argc >= 2){
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
  }

  if(argc >= 3){
    j = atoi(argv[2]);
  }

  if(argc >= 4){
    trials = atoi(argv[3]);
  }

  assert(1 <= n);
  assert(2 <= j);
  assert(1 <= trials);

  srand48(time(NULL));
  long long data = 0;

  for(int tind = 0; tind < trials; tind++){
    int src[n*j];

    for(int cind = 0; cind < n*j; cind++)
      src[cind] = cind/j;

    int done = 0; int steps = 0; 
    int dist[n];

    for(int cind = 0; cind < n; cind++)
      dist[cind] = 0;


    while(!done){
      int cpidx = drand48() * (double)(n*j-steps);
      int coupon = src[cpidx];

      for(int cind=cpidx; cind < n*j-steps-1; cind++)
        src[cind] = src[cind+1];

      steps++;
      dist[coupon]++;

      if(dist[coupon] == 2)
        done = 1;
    }

    data += steps;
  }

  long double expt = (long double)data/(long double)trials;
  printf("[n = %d, j = %d, trials = %d]: %Le\n", 
         n, j, trials, expt);

  exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative solution.

Let's say the first match occurs on the $X$th draw.  We would like to find $\Pr(X>k)$, i.e. the probability that there has been no match by draw $k$, for $k = 0, 1, 2, \dots ,n$. There are $\binom{2n}{k}$ possible selections of $k$ socks, all of which we assume are equally likely.  If there is no match, we must have at most one sock of each of $k$ colors.  There are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to select the $k$ colors, and $2^k$ ways to select the socks of those colors, so $\binom{n}{k}\; 2^k$ ways in all.  So
$$\Pr(X>k) = \frac{\binom{n}{k} \; 2^k}{\binom{2n}{k}}$$

Hence 
$$E(X) = \sum_{k \ge 0}\Pr(X>k) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\binom{n}{k} \; 2^k}{\binom{2n}{k}}$$

Comment: I'd like to show that the last expression here is equal to the closed form $4^n/\binom{2n}{n}$. I note that, if you multiply the sum by $\binom{2n}{n}$, the term in the sum simplifies to $2^k\binom{2n-k}{n}$, so summing that expression from $k=0$ to $n$ should result in $4^n$.....

Comment: @GTonyJacobs You might try induction over $n$.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, and I couldn't make it work. So, I asked about it as a separate SE question, and got a good combinatorial proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750737/identity-involving-sums-of-binomial-coefficients

Comment: There is a link there in the comments to a different version of the same identity, where someone did a complicated induction proof. I like the combinatorial argument more.